# How to route url for adding associated entity with asp.net webapi

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a model looks like below:

```
class File{
    public IList<Tag> Tags;
};
```

According to REST guideline, if I want to add a tag to a file. The URL should looks like this:
http://service.com/File/Id/Tags/ with a PUT method.

Since I'm just beginner of ASP.net MVC WebAPI. My question is how do I route this url to my APIController?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default all API controllers have a route of `/api/SomeApi/` where SomeApiController is an ApiController. There is a seperate route file `App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs` which you can modify to get the routes you need.

You can have routes like the one below

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiById",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiByAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { action = "Get" }
);
```

You can then have an action named "UpdateSomething", which can be accessed by using `somewebsite.com/api/someapi/updatesomething` I hope the above information will be useful to start off with.

**Update:**

for route `/File/Id/Tags` you can have the following route defined

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "MySpecialRoute",
    routeTemplate: "/File/Id/Tags",
    defaults: new { controller = "AbcController", action = "XyzAction" }
);
```

Note: Have not tested the above code

Comment: Yasser, thanks. What puzzle me is how to write this routeTemplate. Take this (http://service.com/File/Id/Tags/) as example. I don't know what the template should look like. Can you help to give an example? Appreciate!